# How to display double quotes(") symbol in a TextView?

Tags: android, xml, string

I'm trying to display some words in double quotes in TextView in an XML file, but it's not working.

```xml
<TextView 
style="@style/TextStyle" 
android:text="message "quote string 1" and "quote string 2" end message" 
android:id="@+id/lblAboutPara3" 
android:autoLink="web"/>
```

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 251):

In the `strings.xml`, you can simply escape special characters (eg double quotes) with a backslash :

```
"message \"quote string 1\" and \"quote string 2\" end message"
```

But in views xml (eg `layout.xml`), you have to use HTML character entities (like `&quot;`) :

```
"message &quot;quote string 1&quot; and &quot;quote string 2&quot; end message"
```

For more, visit http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Comment: It works in strings.xml <string name="double_quote">\"</string> but not in layout.xml

Comment: This answer is incorrect because the OP specifically asks about "double quotes, in Text view in in xml file" not in strings.xml.

Answer (score 81):

Use `&quot;` symbol to solve this hardcode problem :)

```
android:text="message &quot;quote string 1&quot;"
```

Comment: This must be correct ans if you want **"** symbol in layout file without using **string.xml**.

Comment: The fact that you cannot use this in `strings.xml` is a big issue.

Answer (score 16):

use `escape characters`. To display double quote use `\"`

Your code will be

```
android:text="message \"quote string 1\" and "quote string 2\" end message"
```

Answer (score 11):

Please try

```
<TextView 
style="@style/TextStyle" 
android:text='message \"quote string 1\" and \"quote string 2\" end message' 
android:id="@+id/lblAboutPara3" 
android:autoLink="web"/>
```

Answer (score 10):

If you have a double-quote in your string, you must escape it **(\")**. Surrounding the string with single-quotes does not work.

In strings.xml

```
<string name="good_example">This is a \"good string\".</string>
```

**Source** :http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Answer (score 10):

You can use Unicode in any xml file

```
android:text="message \u0022quote string 1\u0022 and \u0022quote string 2\u0022 end message"
```

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0022/index.htm there scroll down to *C/C++/Java source code*

Answer (score 8):

```
TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("&ldquo; " + "YOUR TEXT" + " &rdquo;"));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<TextView 
style="@style/TextStyle" 
android:text='message "quote string 1" and "quote string 2" end message' 
android:id="@+id/lblAboutPara3" 
android:autoLink="web"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use single quotes to wrap the message and you can use as many double-quotes as you want inside the string.

```
android:text='message "quote string 1" and "quote string 2" end message'
```

Comment: with onClick also works perfect