# android:text=" "What If" " how to write this text inside (android:text) attribute,along with double quotes in Android

Tags: android-button

I am new to android, what i want is to show a button containing text including double quotes as given below...but I am getting an error as..... "Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix"

```
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:background="@drawable/nxtbckbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android![enter image description here][1]:text="Continue to  "What if" " />
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the double quotes by using a backslash

`android:text="Continue to  \"What if\" "`

Another option is to use the `&quot;` XML entity for the double quote symbol.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421507/how-to-display-double-quotes-symbol-in-android-text-view) is a question about using double quotes in the text attribute.

Comment: you are so freaking fast in giving answer ;) @DrYap

Comment: Just checking you don't have `![enter image description here][1]` in your source? I have added another option to my answer. Other than that I think the problem must be elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

android:text='Continue to "What if"'

Found it... thanx guyz...