# Characters are not showing properly in russian lanugage

Tags: android, localization

I am facing one kind of weired issue currently in my application. What i am doing is getting response from server in russian language and setting in a textView in one of the screens, but it's not setting it right. Mainly the issue is with double quote, i've tested it in nexus 4, 5 and in other phones but the issue remains. you can better get it from following image what i am trying to say:

[image]

That ending quote is not showing proper, when in reponse that i am getting is all well. I've done lot of googling but failed to find any solution on this. can any one please help me? any kind of help will be appeappreciate. Thanks.

Comment: are you using custom fonts to display that string?

Comment: See this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421507/how-to-display-double-quotes-symbol-in-android-text-view

Comment: @Prag's yes i am using Roboto_light fonts for it

Comment: @Prag's Thanks a lot Prag's for giving me that hint, it was the issue with the custom typeface which was set on that textView, otherwise it's working fine. But this means i can not use that Roboto-Light typeface, can you tell me how can i decorate my text with that typeface without affecting this issue?

Comment: make sure that your font supports double-quote(" ") sign perfectly.. i had same problem with "." (dot) sign... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387026/edittext-fonts-are-not-displaying