# How to add quotes in TextView in the xml file

Tags: android-layout

I am trying to add double quotes in TextView in the xml file, but don't know how to do it. For Example-

```
android:text = "Who designed Python programming language?"
```

I want to see this as Who designed "Python" programming language?
 Please, anybody help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display double quotes(") Symbol in Android Text View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421507/how-to-display-double-quotes-symbol-in-android-text-view)

Answer (score 2):

do it like this

```
android:text="message &quot;quote string 1&quot;"
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421507/how-to-display-double-quotes-symbol-in-android-text-view)